# open web page in ion-content usng in-app-browser

Tags: ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I want to render web page in my app using in-App-Browser. 
that page should display in ion-content section

Is there any way, I can open it. I will really appreciate some help.

Thanks.,

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to share the code you have so far.

I thought that this would be solved by an iFrame but it sounds like the ios store might not approve of that method.

While researching I found this:

[Ionic 4 InAppBrowser for third party payment solution | umeaworks](https://umeaworks.com/2018/08/29/ionic-4-inappbrowser-for-third-party-payment-solution/)

Which talks about how they did it. It seems pretty standard:

```
openBrowser(url: string, target: string) {
    const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.theInAppBrowser.create(url, target, this.options);
    const btn: HTMLElement = this.hiddenBtn.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    if (browser.on('loadstop')) {
        browser.on('loadstop').subscribe((ev: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
            // do whatever is needed here, for example check the url of the browser event
            if (ev.url) {
                // do stuff based on url and url parameters
                // in our solution we got an order id from a confirmation page
            }
            // for the event to trigger we added a hidden button to interact with the screen
            btn.click();
        });
    }
}
```

With these options:

```
options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
    location: 'yes',
    hidden: 'no',
    clearcache: 'yes',
    clearsessioncache: 'yes',
    zoom: 'yes',
    hardwareback: 'yes',
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: 'no',
    shouldPauseOnSuspend: 'no',
    closebuttoncaption: 'Close',
    disallowoverscroll: 'no',
    toolbar: 'yes',
    enableViewportScale: 'no',
    allowInlineMediaPlayback: 'no',
    presentationstyle: 'pagesheet',
    fullscreen: 'yes',
    footer: 'yes'
};
```

The article also notes that a workaround was needed - triggering a fake button press to give focus to the screen otherwise it wouldn't run properly:

```
<ion-button #hiddenBtn style="display:none">hidden</ion-button>
```

and:

```
@ViewChild('hiddenBtn') hiddenBtn: ElementRef;
```

If this doesn't solve your answer, please update your question with details about what you have tried and what specifically went wrong.